# filtering images named in a csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a `csv` file with a list of image names and I want to filter the corresponding images into a new folder. Here is what I hoped could work but it doesn't. I get no error message, so I guess it iterates through the `for` loops but never returns a `True` at the `if`-section but I can't figure out why.
I already tried out `str()` but it still doesn't work.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

```
with open(csvFilePath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inp:
    # run through every row of the file
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        # search for filename in folder
        for file in os.walk(imgFilePath):
            if file == row[column]:
                shutil.copy2(file, newImgPath)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add information _why_ it doesn't work (edit your question). Are there error messages, is the result not as expected, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Found a solution:

Little bit different approach. First we generate a list with all items of the certain column we are interested in. Then we check if the filenames are listed in the list. If `True` we copy the file to the new folder.

```
import os
import shutil
import csv

def test(csvFilePath, imgFilePath, newImgPath):
    img_list = []
    with open(csvFilePath, "r") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
        for rows in csv_reader:
            img_list.append(rows[0])
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(imgFilePath):
        for file in files:
            if file in img_list:
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,file), newImgPath)
```